# Application to import GPO templates into Group Policy Management

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, template

I'm trying to find an application that I can load my GPO backups from `DomainOne` then add some replaces to it such as `Find DomainOne -> Replace with DomainTwo`.  Then click some type of Import button and it auto replace text and then import all my GPOs one by one.

Currently the way provided by Microsoft is horrible!  The migration table does not work on 70% of the URLs found in the GPOs and you also have to import ONE GPO at a time to keep them separate!  My template has 10 GPOs in it and I want my new domain to have 10 corrected GPOs as well.

Is there currently any software out there that does this?